# Looking for web browser plugin to automate text update in modal

Tags: automation

I need to automate updating text in some modals. I will open the modal by myself manually but then **inside** a modal I need to

1. click text "Show hidden fields" so additional fields are available
2. scroll down find field "Billable hours" and update text to 0h
3. then scroll down and click "Update" button

[image]

So after step 1. The automation needs to find input field Billable hours and update the value to 0h.

[image]

The modal is part of Tempo timesheet plugin for Jira.

I tried iMarcors but it did not record anything. Would you have any suggestions how to accomplish the task in browser only?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Automa](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/automa/infppggnoaenmfagbfknfkancpbljcca). Recording is also available but it's always better to just manually set up blocks as that's more reliable.

Comment: looks good but I have troubles to click the test in point #1

Comment: I'm not sure what "test in point #1" is. There are 0 other references to "test" on this page.

Comment: sorry, it is a typpo, I meant *text*. I managed to be able to click the text but now I am facing an issue how to update the text in an input field. I managed to add text but I need to replace the text.

Comment: Use the Forms block with proper CSS selector, Text type and value. Make sure "Clear form value" is selected.

Comment: would you be able to help me with  this question? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85345/how-to-click-select-a-text-in-embeded-modal-in-automa